# CSV to JSON Ruby Script?

Tags: ruby, json, excel

Does anyone know how to write a Ruby script that would convert a csv file to a json file?

The CSV would be in this format:

```
Canon,Digital IXUS 70,"Epic, Epic 100",3x,Yes (lockable),Yes (lockable),Yes
Canon, Digital IXUS 75,"Epic, Epic 100",3x,Yes (lockable),Yes (lockable),Yes
Canon,Digital IXUS 80,"Epic, Epic 100",3x,Yes (lockable),Yes (lockable),Yes
```

and the JSON would need to result in this:

```
{ "aaData": [
[ "Canon" , "Digital IXUS 70" , "3x" , "Yes (lockable)" , "Yes (lockable)" , "Yes"],
[ "Canon" , "Digital IXUS 75" , "3x" , "Yes (lockable)" , "Yes (lockable)" , "Yes"],
[ "Canon" , "Digital IXUS 80" , "3x" , "Yes (lockable)" , "Yes (lockable)" , "Yes"]
]}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is easy in ruby 1.9 where data is your csv data string

```
 require 'csv'
 require 'json'

 CSV.parse(data).to_json
```

Comment: thanks doesn't work for 1.8 and i can't upgrade- what is the correct syntax for 1.87?

Comment: Install gem 'fastercsv' and change CSV to FasterCSV

Comment: ```data = File.open('/path/to/file.csv').read``` to assign data

Answer (score 28):

To go from:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

To

```
[
  {:year => 1997, :make => 'Ford', :model => 'E350', :description => 'ac, abs, moon', :price => 3000.00},
  {:year => 1999, :make => 'Chevy', :model => 'Venture "Extended Edition"', :description => nil, :price => 4900.00},
  {:year => 1999, :make => 'Chevy', :model => 'Venture "Extended Edition, Very Large"', :description => nil, :price => 5000.00},
  {:year => 1996, :make => 'Jeep', :model => 'Grand Cherokee', :description => "MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded", :price => 4799.00}
]
```

Do this:

```
csv = CSV.new(body, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all)
csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
#=> [{:year=>1997, :make=>"Ford", :model=>"E350", :description=>"ac, abs, moon", :price=>3000.0}, {:year=>1999, :make=>"Chevy", :model=>"Venture \"Extended Edition\"", :description=>"", :price=>4900.0}, {:year=>1999, :make=>"Chevy", :model=>"Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"", :description=>nil, :price=>5000.0}, {:year=>1996, :make=>"Jeep", :model=>"Grand Cherokee", :description=>"MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded", :price=>4799.0}]
```

Credit: https://technicalpickles.com/posts/parsing-csv-with-ruby

Answer (score 15):

Building on Josh's example, you can now take it one step further using [CSV::table](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-table):

```
extracted_data   = CSV.table('your/file.csv')
transformed_data = extracted_data.map { |row| row.to_hash }
```

Now you can call `to_json` to use it right away, or write it down to a file, nicely formatted:

```
File.open('your/file.json', 'w') do |file|
  file.puts JSON.pretty_generate(transformed_data)
end
```

Comment: ```extracted_data = CSV.table('your/file.csv', header_converters: nil)``` if you want to keep the headers as the original strings, rather than camelizing and converting to symbols

Answer (score 9):

If you're in a Rails project

```
CSV.parse(csv_string, {headers: true})
csv.map(&:to_h).to_json
```

Comment: Works fine in plain Ruby as well: `ruby -e "require 'csv'; require 'json'" -e "puts CSV.parse(File.open(ARGV[0]), {headers: true}).map(&:to_h).to_json" example.csv`

Answer (score 2):

My solution ended up this way, quite similar to Mariu's

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

csv_table = CSV.parse(File.read('data.csv'), headers: true)
json_string = csv_table.map(&:to_h).to_json

File.open('data.json','w') do |f|
  f.puts(json_string)
end
```