# Convert .json to .csv in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, csv

I want to convert .json file into .csv file using ruby. Pleases help me to do this.

Also propose any tool to achieve this.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357711/csv-to-json-ruby-script

Comment: Do you have an example for the JSON data? JSON in itself may be multidimensional, and csv is 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  JSON.parse(File.open("foo.json").read).each do |hash|
    csv << hash.values
  end
end

puts csv_string
```

Comment: Nice and simple. 
Keep in mind this doesn't take nesting into account and assumes that all objects in the list are the same.

Comment: This is great. It can be enhanced by changing out the `File.open("foo.json")` with `ARGF`. That takes piped in data or filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 13):

To actually write to file...

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("your_csv.csv", "w") do |csv| #open new file for write
  JSON.parse(File.open("your_json.json").read).each do |hash| #open json to parse
    csv << hash.values #write value to file
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the easies way to convert the JSON to CSV in ruby is using json2csv ruby gem.

PS: I may be biased as I am author of this.

[json2csv github repo](https://github.com/korczis/json2csv)

**Running the command**

```
json2csv convert data/sample.json
```

**Input File**

In this particular case it will convert following json:

```
cat data/sample.json

{
    "12345": {
        "Firstname": "Joe",
        "Lastname": "Doe",
        "Address": {
            "Street": "#2140 Taylor Street, 94133",
            "City": "San Francisco",
            "Details": {
                "note": "Pool available"
            }
        }
    },

    "45678": {
        "Firstname": "Jack",
        "Lastname": "Plumber",
        "Address": {
            "Street": "#111 Sutter St, 94104",
            "City": "San Francisco",
            "Details": {
                "note": "Korean Deli near to main entrance"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
cat data/sample.json.csv

id,Firstname,Lastname,Address.Street,Address.City,Address.Details.note
12345,Joe,Doe,"#2140 Taylor Street, 94133",San Francisco,Pool available
45678,Jack,Plumber,"#111 Sutter St, 94104",San Francisco,Korean Deli near to main entrance
```

Comment: Hi @korCZis -- I tried your gem and got the following:json2csv convert errors.json
NameError: undefined local variable or method `errors' for main:Object
        from (irb):3
        from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace or write me an email? korczis@gmail.com

Comment: The gem has not tests. @korCZis let me know when you fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [@Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845170/316700) but adding *csv headers* and *example test*.

```
# utils.rb
require "csv"
module Utils
  def self.array_of_hashes_to_csv(array_of_hashes)
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << array_of_hashes.first.keys
      array_of_hashes.each { |hash| csv << hash.values }
    end
  end
end

# utils_test.rb
class UtilsTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_array_of_hashes_to_csv
    array_of_hashes = [
      { :key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2" },
      { :key1 => "value3", :key2 => "value4" }
    ]
    expected_result = "key1,key2\nvalue1,value2\nvalue3,value4\n"
    assert_equal(expected_result, Utils.array_of_hashes_to_csv(array_of_hashes))
  end
end
```

Comment: This assumes that all objects in the list have the same keys.. In case, you have the object `[{ :key1 => "value1" }, { :key1 => "value3", :key2 => "value4" }]` then you will have only one column `key1`

Answer (score 3):

Ruby code to convert from json to csv.

Handles arrays by converting them to double quoted strings.

```
#json-to-csv.rb
require 'json'
require 'csv'

file = File.read('./input.json')
hash = JSON.parse(file)

CSV.open('./output.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  headers = hash.first.keys
  csv << headers

  hash.each do |item|
    values = item.values
    printable_values = Array.new
    values.each do |value|

      printable_values << value.to_s.gsub(/\[|\]/,'').gsub(/"/,'\'')

    end

    csv << printable_values

  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

This functionality described below is now available as a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/json_converter).  After installing with `gem install json_converter`, the following snippet can be used to generate a CSV from a valid JSON string or object:

```
require 'json_converter'
json_converter= JsonConverter.new

# Assume json is a valid JSON string or object
csv = json_converter.generate_csv json
```

**Original Answer:**

If your JSON data is relatively simple (no nesting or arrays), Alex's answer is probably the cleanest way of handling this problem.

However, if you *do* need to take arrays and nested objects into account, I've attempted to port a [web version](https://github.com/konklone/json) of such a converter to ruby.  It can be found [here](https://github.com/cescue/json-to-csv/blob/master/json_to_csv.rb).  The methods that handle the actual restructuring of data are `array_from` and `flatten`.

The `array_from` method attempts to identify what a "row" of data looks like for a given dataset.  It is not perfect, and you may want to tweak this part for different datasets.

```
# Attempt to identify what a "row" should look like
def array_from(json)
  queue, next_item = [], json
  while !next_item.nil?

    return next_item if next_item.is_a? Array

    if next_item.is_a? Hash
      next_item.each do |k, v|
        queue.push next_item[k]
      end
    end

    next_item = queue.shift
  end

  return [json]
end
```

The `flatten` method recursively iterates over the JSON object(s), and generates an object that represents headers and values.  If an object is nested, the header for its column will be prefixed with its parent key(s), delimited by the `/` character.

```
# The path argument is used to construct header columns for nested elements
def flatten(object, path='')
  scalars = [String, Integer, Fixnum, FalseClass, TrueClass]
  columns = {}

  if [Hash, Array].include? object.class
    object.each do |k, v|
      new_columns = flatten(v, "#{path}#{k}/") if object.class == Hash
      new_columns = flatten(k, "#{path}#{k}/") if object.class == Array
      columns = columns.merge new_columns
    end

    return columns
  elsif scalars.include? object.class
      # Remove trailing slash from path
      end_path = path[0, path.length - 1]
      columns[end_path] = object
      return columns
  else
    return {}
  end
end
```

If there are any `null` values in the original JSON, you'll need to convert these to something other than `nil` before attempting the conversion - you'll generally end up with uneven rows if you don't.  The `nils_to_strings` method handles that:

```
# Recursively convert all nil values of a hash to empty strings
def nils_to_strings(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), object|
    case v
    when Hash
      object[k] = nils_to_strings v
    when nil
      object[k] = ''
    else
      object[k] = v
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a brief example of how this would be used:

```
json = JSON.parse(File.open('in.json').read)
in_array = array_from json
in_array.map! { |x| nils_to_strings x }

out_array = []
in_array.each do |row|
  out_array[out_array.length] = flatten row
end

headers_written = false
CSV.open('out.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  out_array.each do |row|
    csv << row.keys && headers_written = true if headers_written === false
    csv << row.values
  end
end
```

And finally, here's some example input/output:

Input:

```
{
  "Forms": [
    {
      "Form": {
        "id": "x",
        "version_id": "x",
        "name": "x",
        "category": "",
        "subcategory": null,
        "is_template": null,
        "moderation_status": "x",
        "display_status": "x",
        "use_ssl": "x",
        "modified": "x",
        "Aggregate_metadata": {
          "id": "x",
          "response_count": "x",
          "submitted_count": "x",
          "saved_count": "x",
          "unread_count": "x",
          "dropout_rate": "x",
          "average_completion_time": null,
          "is_uptodate": "x"
        }
      },
      "User": {
        "username": "somedude@example.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "Form": {
        "id": "x",
        "version_id": "x",
        "name": "x",
        "category": "",
        "subcategory": null,
        "is_template": null,
        "moderation_status": "x",
        "display_status": "x",
        "use_ssl": "x",
        "modified": "x",
        "Aggregate_metadata": {
          "id": "x",
          "response_count": "x",
          "submitted_count": "x",
          "saved_count": "x",
          "unread_count": "x",
          "dropout_rate": "x",
          "average_completion_time": null,
          "is_uptodate": "x"
        }
      },
      "User": {
        "username": "somedude@example.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
Form/id,Form/version_id,Form/name,Form/category,Form/subcategory,Form/is_template,Form/moderation_status,Form/display_status,Form/use_ssl,Form/modified,Form/Aggregate_metadata/id,Form/Aggregate_metadata/response_count,Form/Aggregate_metadata/submitted_count,Form/Aggregate_metadata/saved_count,Form/Aggregate_metadata/unread_count,Form/Aggregate_metadata/dropout_rate,Form/Aggregate_metadata/average_completion_time,Form/Aggregate_metadata/is_uptodate,User/username
x,x,x,"","","",x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,"",x,somedude@example.com
x,x,x,"","","",x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,"",x,somedude@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is handle headers & nested json.

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

@headers = []
file = File.open('file.json')
JSON.parse(file.read).each do |h|
  h.keys.each do |key|
    @headers << key
  end
end

uniq_headers = @headers.uniq
file = File.open('file.json')
finalrow = []

JSON.parse(file.read).each do |h|
  final = {}
  @headers.each do |key2|
    final[key2] = h[key2]
  end

  finalrow << final
end

CSV.open('output.csv' , 'w') do |csv|
  csv << uniq_headers
  finalrow.each do |deal|
    csv << deal.values
  end
end
```