# Securely transfer a banch of files from one Heroku app to another

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, transfer

I need to setup a Heroku app (python) which would perform scheduled tasks that include fetching a set of data (.csv an .html) files from other Heroku app (ROR) and returning a result back to that app.

Also it should be restricted only to my app to be able to connect to the ROR app because it deals with sensitive information. There would be from 20 to 100 files each time so I want them to be compressed somehow to transfer them quiclky (to avoid bothering the server for too long).

I'm interested in possible ways to accomplish it. The first thought is to send HTTP GET request to the ROR app and fetch the necessary files yet it generally not secured at all. Would SCP work in some way in this situation or you have any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing a secured JSON or XML API to transfer the data from app to app,. Once the data is received I would then generate the .csv or .html files from the received data. It keeps things clean and easy to modify for future revisions because now you'll have an API to interact with.

Comment: Hm, actually it's a kind of a plan. I'll try to make things up in this way to see if it would work good.

Comment: Take a look at this to convert the received data in JSON to CSV. This is by far your best option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845015/convert-json-to-csv-in-ruby