# How to click on Xpath element and download csv document using a shell script?

Tags: shell, xpath

I am building an R script that automates the download of a csv file from a website everyday. The script works fine on my personal computer but the script fails to run on my computer at work ( I am using the RSelenium package) (both a firewall issue and a software issue- Chrome keeps crashing when the script prompts it to open remotely).

I was thinking about a way to use curl in a shell script to locate the Xpath (which I already have) and click on the element (the "Download CSV" button) via the shell script. The said Xpath is "//*[@id="eventSearch"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button".

The website is below:
https://www.vegasmeansbusiness.com/planning-tools/convention-calendar/

Note that if you navigate to the website you will see a "Download Events as CSV" button.

So far I have accessed the body and have tried to download the data to no avail.
Below is what I have so far (It is fair to say that I know very little about shell scripting) so any help is appreciated.

```
curl -sL "https://www.vegasmeansbusiness.com/planning-tools/convention-calendar/" xpup '/*/body
```

Comment: I will not work that way due to the dynamic value of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl approach fails because the actual data is retrieved from a REST API endpoint via JSON and then converted and served as CSV.

Either use browser automation like Selenium or access the API directly.

You can try to query the endpoint yourself:

```
curl -sL "https://www.vegasmeansbusiness.com/includes/rest_v2/plugins_events_events/find/?json=%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22calendarid%22%3A%22conventions%22%2C%22dates%22%3A%7B%22%24elemMatch%22%3A%7B%22eventDate%22%3A%7B%22%24gte%22%3A%7B%22%24date%22%3A%222018-09-23T07%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%7D%2C%22%24lte%22%3A%7B%22%24date%22%3A%222019-09-24T06%3A59%3A59.000Z%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22convention.roomattend%22%3A%7B%22%24gte%22%3A100%7D%7D%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22skip%22%3A0%2C%22fields%22%3A%7B%22title%22%3A1%2C%22startDate%22%3A1%2C%22endDate%22%3A1%2C%22convention_facilities.title%22%3A1%2C%22convention.roomattend%22%3A1%2C%22convention.hostcompany%22%3A1%2C%22convention.hosturl%22%3A1%7D%2C%22castDocs%22%3Afalse%2C%22count%22%3Afalse%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22startDate%22%3A1%2C%22title%22%3A1%7D%2C%22hooks%22%3A%5B%22afterFind_convention_facilities%22%5D%7D%7D&token=8d1a7610fe6a76ff80a76a1e1a481d2e" > events.json
```

Then use any [tool](https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv) or [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845015/convert-json-to-csv-in-ruby) to convert the json ton CSV.

However, the result may look a little different and this can break any moment if there is any change on the other side. There is also a token in the URL string that certainly will expire at some point.

Comment: Thank you, how did you get this json file ?

Comment: I observed the network traffic of the page whilst clicking the download button.

Comment: Ok the reason i ask is because i can find a way to generate the json file as a line of code right before the conversion to csv (all in R) and then the script will theoretically always map the json file regardless of whether the token changes. I am assuming there is no systematic way of extracting the json file ? Thank you