# Curl: how to pass value of specific key from file

Tags: bash, curl

wasn't able to find and I'm not sure if it possible at all. I know that I can pass the whole payload via @file.json, something like

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json \
http://localhost/api/v3/endpoint 

$ cat test.json
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2"
}
```

But now I need to upload gpg public key and I can't store the key inside test.json. What I need is something like

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://localhost/api/v3/endpoint \
-d '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "@gpg-public.key"}'
```

Thanks in advance

As an option in bash I can use the following

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://localhost/api/v3/endpoint \
-d "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"$(cat gpg-public.key)\"}"
```

but I'm looking for more elegant way

Comment: unless you can guarantee that the gpg file doesn't contain `\n` (it almost certainly does!!)  or `"`, or anything else that needs to be json-escaped , your proposed bash cat method is not safe, it will create a corrupted/invalid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule of JSON is to use a tool that knows JSON to generate dynamic values. A good tool is `jq`. Now, instead of storing a JSON file on disk, store a `jq` filter that can act as a *template* for your JSON file.

```
# test.jq
{
  key1: "value1",
  key2: $gpg
}
```

Now, you can run `jq` using this template as a filter, and supply a value for it to replace `$gpg`:

```
$ jq -n -f test.jq --arg gpg hi
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "hi"
}
```

Once you have this command, you can use it to pass the generated JSON directly to `curl` via standard input; the `-d` option can take `@-` as an argument to read from standard input.

```
jq -n -f test.q --arg gpg hi | curl ... -d @-
```

For simple jobs, you can specify the filter on the command line instead of reading it from a file.

```
jq -n '{key1: "value1", key2: $gpg}' --arg gpg hi | curl -d @-
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't say this is more elegant, but at least it's different.

```
jq -Rn '{key2: input}' <pgp-public.key |
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' test.json - |
curl -d @- ...
```

Credit for the `jq` hacks: [Simo Kinnunen's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904276/874188) and [Charles Duffy's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862221/874188).

Comment: Put a `jq` filter based on `test.json`, like `{key1: "value1", key2: $pgp}`, in a file, and then you can make a single `jq` call: `jq -n --arg pgp "$(<gpg-public.key)" -f test.jq | curl -d @-`.

Comment: @chepner what is ```-f test.jq``` or it's just a typo and should be test.json?

Comment: `-f` tells `jq` to read the filter from the given file, rather than from a command line argument. If `test.jq` contains `.`, then `jq -f test.jq` is equivalent to `jq '.'`.

Comment: But if `test.json` is a given and cannot be modified, putting `key2: $pgp` inside it is a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

use multipart/form-data with the -F parameter, it supports uploading multiple files at once.

`curl -F json=@test.json -F pgp=@pgp-public.key http://localhost/api/v3/endpoint`

ofc, the API endpoint will also need to support multipart/form-data for this to work.

edit: going by your comments, if you *have* to send a single json file, then edit the json file as needed and send the edited version, unfortunately bash is not a suitable language for editing json (although i'm sure it's *[possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50873696/1067003)*), i'd recommend using some other scripting language for that. here's an example with php-cli to edit the json, then sending the edited json to curl via stdin:

```
php -r '$p=json_decode(file_get_contents("test.json"),true);$p["key2"]=file_get_contents("pgp-public.key");echo json_encode($p);' | 
curl -d @- -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/v3/endpoint
```

(but any language with json support should suffice, like python/perl/php)

Comment: @ALex_hha then use a better scripting language. `php -r '$p=json_decode(file_get_contents("test.json"),true);$p["key2"]=file_get_contents("pgp-public.key");echo json_encode($p);' | curl -d @- -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/v3/endpoint`