# Create JSON from string with format "key1=value1,key2=value2" using jq

Tags: json, bash, csv, parsing, jq

I'm trying to create a json file from a string with the following format:

```
string="key1=value1,key2=value2"
```

Is there a way to create a json using jq by specifying the `=` and `,` symbols as separators for the keys and values?

The output I'm looking for would be:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2” :”value2"}
```

I've tried to use this post as a reference:
[Create JSON using jq from pipe-separated keys and values in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860529/create-json-using-jq-from-pipe-separated-keys-and-values-in-bash) -- however, it expects input that contains a line with only keys, before later lines with only values; here, the keys and values are all interspersed.

Comment: You can't have comma delimited key/value pairs without having a way of encoding the delimiters. How is anyone supposed to interpret that?

Comment: Editing a question into a completely distinct follow-up question *after it already received answers addressing the original question* is against the rules here.

Comment: See [What to do when someone answers: Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal); updating a question in a way that invalidates previously-correct answers is the former. If you have a different variant of the question, ask it as a new question.

Comment: See also [What is the best way to ask follow-up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a reduce-free solution that assumes `string` is the shell variable (not part of the string to be parsed), and that parsing of the string can be accomplished by first splitting on ",":

```
jq -R 'split(",")
       | map( index("=") as $i | {(.[0:$i]) : .[$i+1:]})
       | add' <<< "$string"
```

Notice that this allows "=" to appear within the values.

The only trickiness here is that when a key name is specified programmatically, it must be enclosed within parentheses.

### Supplemental question

> string="key1=value1|key2=value2,value3|key3=value4"

In this case, you would first split on "|", and then find the first occurrence of "=":

```
split("|")
| map( index("=") as $i | {(.[0:$i]) : .[$i+1:]})
| add
| map_values(if index(",") then split(",") else . end)
```

Output:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": [
    "value2",
    "value3"
  ],
  "key3": "value4"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was wondering if the way you use split could be altered to handle multi-value keys whose values are separated by commas? I've edited my original question to give an example of what I mean. It seems as if the current solution parses the second value as a key-value pair itself.

Comment: In future, if you have a new question, it will probably be best for everyone if you ask a new SO question.

Comment: @peak, ...on which point, I'd argue that we should be pressing for a new question rather than rewarding chameleon questions; that's certainly the consensus on meta.

Answer (score 2):

```
string="key1=value1,key2=value2"

jq -Rc '
split(",")
| [.[] | match( "([^=]*)=(.*)" )]
| reduce .[].captures as $item ({}; .[$item[0].string]=$item[1].string)
' <<<"$string"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n "key1=value1,key2=value2" | \
jq -csR '[split(",")[]|split("=") | {(.[0]): .[1]}]|add'
```

this gives

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```